How do I get the "High Confidence/Other" indicator for Github API Secret Scanner alerts?
I see that there is an API for getting Github Secret Scanner alerts here:
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/secret-scanning/secret-scanning?apiVersion=2022-11-28
But if I view them on the website they are broken into two categories High and Other:

I noticed that when I call the api for an org or a repo level, I only get back the "High" items.
How can I also include the "Other" in my api call and what data in the results helps me differentiate them.
